# ary[start, length]. out of boundary number giving [ ] output?

Tags: ruby, arrays

While going over the Array class from the Ruby 2.0.0 docs, I noticed something I can't explain. The following is a direct example from the [Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html):

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ]
a[6, 1]                #=> nil
a[5]                   #=> nil
a[5, 1]                #=> []
```

Could some one explain to me why `a[5, 1]` has the output `[ ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of `[]` are the same as for `slice` when two integers are provided. As explained in http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice, when the first integer points to the end of the array, the empty array will be returned.

Comment: I must have missed that part. That explains it!